# Web scraping with R, How does one "print('NA')" for <div>'s that lack <p>'s?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am scraping a series of news pages to create a .csv, however some of the articles contain no textual data. For these I want to print "NA" - how can this be done?

Code sample:

```
indwebpage <- read_html(fullUrl)
bodyline <- indwebpage %>% html_node(".detail_con") %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% replace(!nzchar(.), NA)
bodyline <- strsplit(bodyline, "\\W")
bodyline <- unlist(bodyline)
bodyline <- bodyline[which(bodyline!="")]
bodyline <- paste(bodyline, sep=" ", collapse = " ")
write(bodyline, file = "bodyline.csv", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: We can't give an exact answer unless you give us an example. From my experience, if the node contains no textual data. It should return `NULL`, and you can check it by using `is.null(x)`. You can replace the content with `NA` if the condition is true.

Comment: @YifuYan Thanks for the assist, but the `is.null(x)` came back false. However! I tweaked `replace(!nzchar(.), "NA")` and it's working as desired.